# MEF and seeing what is in the container

Tags: mef

When you are dealing with MEF and you have built the MEF Container.

It is possible to find out what is inside your MEF container once it has been built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, either:

1 - Debugger... stepping into your code, you'll be able to use debugging features built into Visual Studio to look into your container.

[image]

2 - Composition Analysis Tool - (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576068.aspx) - which is a command-line tool for analysing assemblies to discover what parts are available.

3 - If you are using ASP.NET with Glimpse, you might want to look at a plugin I started developing that explores your container too: (https://github.com/Antaris/Glimpse.MEF):

[image]

[image]

4 - Roll your own.

Comment: Yes, perfect thanks, and this is in two lines of 

var name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);

return Enumerable.Any(_container.Catalog.Parts.SelectMany(part => part.ExportDefinitions), e => e.ContractName == name) ? _container.GetExportedValue<object>(name) : null;